# Yii2 заполнение связанного поля

Tags: yii2, связь

Как сделать так, чтобы в таблице, которая связыватся с другой таблицей при создании заполнялся FK к другой. 
То есть у меня есть таблица Agent, в которой есть поле broker_id, по которому она связывает брокерскую компанию с агентами. Но когда я создаю нового агента, там присутствует чертово поле broker_id, которое нужно заполнить именно точным айдишником компании. 
Догадываюсь, что это должно быть в ЭкшнКриэйт таблицы контроллера Agents, но вот этот код не работает:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Agent();
        $model->broker_id = $model->broker->id;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view','id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

В файле _form.php строку ввода broker_id удалил, а вот в екшнКриэйт нужно что-то сделать, чтобы при создании поле broker_id само заполнялось, а то если у меня будет 100 компаний, я не могу знать id каждого)

Comment: А чем должно заполнятся поле broker_id по логике приложения?

Comment: Не совсем понятна связь, брокер - агент - компания. Кто, кому кто и какие типы связей. Лучше структуру базы покажите, так будет понятней

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно при создании агента к примеру через `select` выбирать компанию, которой он принадлежит, что-то вроде:

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
...

echo $form->field($model, 'company')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(), 'id', 'company_name'), [
    'options' => [
        $model->company => ['selected' => true]
    ],
    'prompt' => 'Не выбрано...'
])->label('Выберите компанию');
```

Comment: Спасибо, до вашего ответа думал об этом варианте, но не знал, как это реализовать. Очень помогло)

Comment: Спасибо, мне тоже очень помогло!

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!!!

Answer (score 0):

Это структура таблицы broker_company

[image: Broker company]

, а это структура таблицы agents 
[image: agents] 
broker_company может иметь много agents, а agent может сосстоять только в одной broker_company. Связь между ними через поле broker_id в таблице agents.
Так в чем сама проблема - когда я создаю экземпляр broker_company, то все нормально, но когда я создаю экземпляр agent, мне нужно заполнять вручную поле broker_id. Как сделать так, чтобы при создании экземпляра agent, поле broker_id заполнялось значением broker_company->id?

Comment: А как вы представляете себе алгоритм автоматического заполнения поля **broker_id**? Как вновь созданный агент должен понять к какой из  **broker_company** он относится?

Comment: И на будущее я бы рекомендовал называть как-то структурировано имена таблиц и столбцов. А то без пол литра не разобраться. что с чем связанно и что из себя представляет